# Unable to insert NULL values to a NOT NULL date field after upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, sql-null

I upgraded from MySQL 5.7.26 to 8.0.20.

One of the tables have not null column with TIMESTAMP data type with a default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

On 5.7.26 ,
if an insert statement like the following was run, it used to execute successfully and the not null column used to be populated with default value i.e. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
mysql>insert into test_field ( object_type, dataType, fieldSize, hiddenFlag , fieldLabel, fieldName, modified_date) values ('LEAD', 13, 44, 1, 'Date Last Updated_testing1', 'test_Insert_test1', NULL);
```

Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

After upgrading to 8.0.20, I am getting error :

```
mysql>insert into test_field ( object_type, dataType, fieldSize, hiddenFlag , fieldLabel, fieldName, modified_date) values ('LEAD', 13, 44, 1, 'Date Last Updated_testing1', 'test_Insert_test1', NULL);
```

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'modified_date' cannot be null

Comment: can you please show us a create table, to reproduce it, also take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: in MySQL 8+ you need to specify whether it is `default` or `not`. when you write `null` which is a `generic attribute` it tries to insert `null` but as it is `not null` so use `default` instead and it will work.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `test_field` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fieldLabel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   ....
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `hiddenFlag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukey_object_fieldName` (`object_type`,`fieldName`),
  KEY `fkey_cf_datatype` (`dataType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the behavior of MySQL as regard to inserting `null` to a non-`nullable` column for which a `default` value is set up has changed between versions 5.7 and 8.0. However, [it is documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) that what happens in this case depends on whether strict mode is enabled:

> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables, an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows are inserted.
> - If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit default value for the column data type.

Probably, your fresh 8.0 installation has strict mode enabled, while your it was disable in your 5.7 database.

A possible workaround is to use `DEFAUT` instead of `NULL`:

```
insert into test_field (object_type, dataType, fieldSize, hiddenFlag , fieldLabel, fieldName, modified_date) 
values ('LEAD', 13, 44, 1, 'Date Last Updated_testing1', 'test_Insert_test1', DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Both versions have innodb_strict_mode on globally